# Get egress traffic from GAR respository

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-artifact-registry

I work on a product where we provide our customers with GAR (Google Artifact Registry) repositories. In order to understand the consumption and use our customers do of the registries, we would like to get metrics on the egress traffic generated from them.
Do you know of any way we can get that information? I have been looking at the information registered in the `Audit Logs` after enabling the `data read` and `data write` logs for the `Artifact Registry API`, but it seems no information recorded could give me what I want. Besides that, I couldn't find any other way of getting this information.

Any idea?

Comment: You can use VPC flow logs for monitoring the traffic flow to your GAR and filter them. go through this \[doc\](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/flow-logs) for more information<br>